# How do l return the token from a field value in a Cloud Functions?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cloud-messaging

l am getting this error:
Registration token(s) provided to sendToDevice() must be a non-empty string or a non-empty array.
at FirebaseMessagingError.FirebaseError [as constructor] (/workspace/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:44:28)

```
exports.mediZim = functions.firestore.document("users/{user}/responses/{pharmacy}")
    .onCreate((change, context) => {
        const myData = change.data();
        const tokens = [];
        fstore.collection("pharmacies").doc(myData.uid).collection("userTokens").get().then((snap) => {
            return snap.forEach((element) => {
                tokens.push(element.data().token);
            });
        });
        return fcm.sendToDevice(tokens, {
            data: {
                title: "Medi-Zim",
                body: change.data().message,
                sound: "default",
            },
        });
    });
```

In "users/{user}/responses/{pharmacy}" l have this
[Firestore Field uid available](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BQb48.png)

l use the uid to get the document ID in another collection so that l can grab usertokens that are feedin to that Document. l then send want to send the notification to the tokens.
[Error with eslint after trying answers 1 and 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dRScy.png)
[Another Try From answer 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i0He8.png)

This is the error l am getting from Cloud Functions:

Registration token(s) provided to sendToDevice() must be a non-empty string or a non-empty array.
at FirebaseMessagingError.FirebaseError [as constructor] (/workspace/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:44:28)

Comment: Can you try adding `console.log(tokens.length)` to see if the array is empty ?

Comment: @Dharmaraj deploying now will get back to you soon

Comment: @Dharmaraj Nothing is showing on the Firebase logs

Comment: I have posted an answer. There were a couple of issues. Please let me know if that works. If it does then you can accept it by clicking on the check icon so others know the question is resolved. Else please share further queries.

Comment: @Dharmaraj l just tried your code, ```lint``` gave me the follwing error, 
error  Parsing error: Unexpected token => 
this is on this line ```.onCreate(async (change, context) => {```

Comment: I doubt if the error is there tbh,

Comment: Can you try `.onCreate(async function(change, context) { . . . })`?

Comment: l have made the changes

Comment: Apologies but can you share the screenshot when you were using arrow function?  `.onCreate(async (change, context) => {...})`

Comment: Update: I just tried to deploy the function with same code and it was deployed successfully.

Comment: Are you using Eslint for that Project?

Comment: Nope, I was going to suggest try disabling it temporarily.

Comment: l see. @Tarik Huber gave me a solution on his edit. it worked with ESLint. No errors but the notification did not come to my device

Comment: Not sure about the delay. Check the Functions logs maybe if it was ran successfully.

Comment: l just checked but nothing. And even now there is still nothing

Comment: l just figured why. the solution l was given is successfully running however because the function onCreate itself is NOT returning  a promise /future it means Cloud Functions will do garbage collection and end all processes before the Message has been sent.  There must be another way to fulfill this excution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is not with the tokens but with the `async` code.

Try the code like this:

```js
exports.mediZim = functions.firestore
  .document("users/{user}/responses/{pharmacy}")
  .onCreate((change, context) => {
    const myData = change.data();

    return fstore
      .collection("pharmacies")
      .doc(myData.uid)
      .collection("userTokens")
      .get()
      .then((snap) => {
        const tokens = [];

        snap.forEach((element) => {
          tokens.push(element.data().token);
        });

        return fcm.sendToDevice(tokens, {
          data: {
            title: "Medi-Zim",
            body: change.data().message,
            sound: "default",
          },
        });
      });
  });
```

The problem with your code was that you returned the `fcm.sendToDevice` without waiting for the `get` call to finish. So you would always send the notifications to an empty array and get that error.

Comment: Also got error from ```lint``` :  ```error  Parsing error: Unexpected token =>``` 
Same line with @Dharmaraj which is 
```.onCreate(async (change, context) => {```

Comment: How are your tokesn stored in the database? The error just says that there is no field `token`

Comment: field Values in in a document as strings

Comment: When l execute ```async await``` with the ```onCreate``` function eslint now comes to me saying it has ```error  Parsing error: Unexpected token =>``` Which means there is a syntax error on that line

Comment: I have updated the code so it doesn't use async await but the old styling with the bugfix to work properly.

Comment: let me try it out

Comment: This one worked no Errors from cloud functions console. The Notification did not Come though. but l think thats another issue let me vote yours as Correct

Answer (score 0):

The return statement executes before the loop is complete and the tokens are in the array.

Please try the exact same code below and let me know if it works.

```
exports.mediZim = functions.firestore.document("users/{user}/responses/{pharmacy}")
    .onCreate(async (change, context) => {
        const myData = change.data();
        const tokens = [];
        const tokenDocs = await fstore.collection("pharmacies").doc(myData.uid).collection("userTokens").get()
        tokenDocs.docs.forEach((doc) => {
            tokens.push(doc.data().token);
        });
        return fcm.sendToDevice(tokens, {
            data: {
                title: "Medi-Zim",
                body: change.data().message,
                sound: "default",
            },
        });
    });
```

I have used `async-await` instead of chaining promise. This should now wait for the response from Firestore and then return the FCM function.

Comment: We have almost the same answer ;) You are missing the `await` in your get call.

Comment: @TarikHuber thanks :D I missed it out file copying the original code :')

Comment: Checking please wait... l will add the await

Comment: same error error  ```Parsing error: Unexpected token =>```

Comment: @PardonJuru try normal function.. `..onCreate(async function (change, context) { . . .})`

Comment: @Dharmaraj Sorry about this. lm willing to try more options

95:21  error  Parsing error: Unexpected token function

✖ 1 problem (1 error, 0 warnings)

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! functions@ lint: `eslint .`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the functions@ lint script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

Comment: @PardonJuru do you mind sharing some screenshots of both code and the terminal error? You can add the pics in your question.